# Sql Query performance for string operations?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, performance

I want to **strip last 4 char** of a varchar(255) string in a self join condition operation.
which of these string operation is faster.

```
Example: link field 

1, '100-200-300-'
2, '100-200-400-'
3, '100-200-300-400-'

1. left(a.link, len(a.link)-4) = left(b.link, len(b.link)-4)
// OR 
2. substring(reverse(a.link), 4, 255) = substring(reverse(b.link), 4, 255)
```

or I should use some other way, if  I consider performance?

Comment: Looks like something you could micro-benchmark yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really care about performance then you use a proper index. Create a computed persisted column, index it and join on it:

```
alter table tablename add sublink =  left(a.link, len(a.link)-4) persisted;
create index indexname on tablename(sublink);

...

select...
from...
join... on a.sublink = b.sublink;
```

This is just an example. In a real case, the correct shape and composition of index would have to be properly analyzed (eg. decide what other columns are needed as keys, include or filter on the index). Its benefits woudl have to be balanced against the update costs added.

[Designing Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190804.aspx) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important, you put that substring into its own field and index it.

Comparing your options the `left(len())` variant will almost certainly be faster than the `substring(reverse())` variant since `reverse()` has to create a new string from the original one and will be slower than just getting the length.

What about `right(a.link, 4)` instead?

Comment: right(a.link, 4) is the expression that OP wants to _ignore_.

Comment: right function won't work since i need the left part. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ah, missed the part where you wanted to strip the last 4 chars from the original value.