# Validate uniquness in ActiveRecord on part of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.1

Lets say I have `registration_id` attribute on `Dummy` model.
Its data type is string.
Its length can be anything from 10-14 characters but I want to put a uniqueness validation **on last 10 characters only**. (weird but true)

Now how can I achieve this?

What I have thought of:

1. Create another attribute `last_ten_chars_registration_id` in `Dummy` table to hold last 10 characters and put uniqueness on this attribute.
   (As Computed attributes apparently don't work for uniqueness validations)
2. I can create a custom validator and write a query.
   I am not sure (may be `like` query)

Can anyone suggest me any better way to achieve this?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: I like the `last_ten_chars_registration_id` idea. And you can index the column to get good performance on those uniqueness queries.  Database performance is not completely my wheelhouse, but I would imagine that `like` query would not be so performant over time and growth.

Comment: Not to totally disagree, but normalization over optimization. Unless there is a justification for optimizing such as millions of records or slow queries, I still believe LIKE check is better. If you have two columns with same data, how sure can you be that it will never get out of sync, keeping them matching would require extra logic elsewhere. The custom validation enforces the business logic that you can't have two records with reg IDs with same last 10 chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom validator like this.

```
class Dummy < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with RegistrationValidator, :fields => [:registration_id]

  # Whatever else...
end

class RegistrationValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    reg_id = record.registration_id.last(10).join
    if Dummy.where('registration_id LIKE ?',"%#{reg_id}")
      record.errors[:registration_id] << "Registration ID taken!"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Fixed a typo in the record.registration_id.

Answer (score 0):

Same as GoGoCarl, I also think it largely depends on the performance you require. A custom query (not using `LIKE` but rather the `RIGHT(registration_id, 10)` function, at least in MySQL) will I think do fine unless the `Dummy` table is huge or you need the query to be super fast. In that case, I too would do the special column with the last 10 chars, and an accompanying db index.

A pragmatic solution might be to first go the custom query route as it seems simpler to implement to me, and later, if performance starts to suffer, switch to the special column.

You could also do your own benchmarks, e.g. populate a test `Dummy` table with the number of records you expect and see for yourself if the performance is OK with you or not.

See also this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228374/sql-query-performance-for-string-operations) on string SQL functions performance where the solutions are similar.